# Is there any easy way to mount multiple single gang low voltage panels in a multi-gang box?

Tags: wiring, data-wiring, cabling, junction-box

So, a combination of AT&T, Comcast, and the previous owner of my house and made an absolute mess out of the area I'm wanting to use as the network hub of my house. There are five outlets, one for AT&T's modem (it's branded), one for Comcast's modem (the previous owner went with comcast), two for network connections, and one for power. None of them are spaced evenly, and the plates are all different colors.

I have access to the back of the wall, and am considering a single gang box for the outlet, and one large multigang box for all the lower voltage connections. The problem is, these others are of course all single gang plates, so they won't fit well into a multigang box. Googling reveals no quick and easy cutting method. I'm considering a few possibilities of how to make this work, but was wondering if there was a tried and true method that anyone knew of before I head into uncharted waters. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: I think we might need a picture.  I can't understand what's going on here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Standard approach is to use "Keystone jacks" (for whatever type of wire connection - there are all sorts.) and slot them into a plate that takes them (up to 6 will go in a single-gang box, with the right cover, double-width with 12 holes are common, 1, 2 or 4 for a single-gang is also common.)

A picture (or several) would help to inform further.

Presumably you have 2X Cat5e or Cat6 (house network), one coaxial cable connection (Comcast), and one phone line connection, given your described service providers and assuming that "AT&T's modem" is a DSL so that it would be connected to a phone line. If that's not the case, there are probably still keystone jacks for whatever you have - you may even have some keystone jacks in single-port plates that could just be moved to a multi-port plate.

Comment: They also make keystone plates that fit the decora style covers.  With these you can fit a whatever gang box.  example of  6 slot is here:  http://www.amazon.com/CableWholesale-Decora-Insert-Keystone-302-6D-W/dp/B00749SCEQ   they also come in 1,2,3 and 4 slots.

Comment: I didn't realize it, but you're right, some of the existing ports are in keystone plates, and if they come in double wide configurations, that should cover all the connections (I have 6 network wires as they go to several areas in the house). The AT&T is a custom wallplate that houses some circuitry, but here is no reason I couldn't obscure that circuit board in the wall while having it connected to the wallplate. I'll post pictures when i get home this afternoon, but I'm marking this as the accepted answer.